# Use same JQuery for multiple divs but apply it one div at a time

Tags: jquery, html, each, accordion

I have two Bootstrap accordions. Each accordion has multiple things happening in them via JQuery. But when I click on one accoridion both are applying the JQuery I wrote at the same time, and I want them to happen one at a time. I have provided a codepen.

I would like to use the same JQuery for both panels so I don't have to write the same code twice in JQuery.

Here is my codepen.

https://codepen.io/sazad/pen/XPWXYR

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" class="notify-check">
                <span class="slider round"></span>
            </label>
            <div class="disabled-overlay"></div>
            <div id="accordion">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                        <button class="btn btn-title center" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">PRICE <i class="caret-icon fas fa-caret-down hide"></i>
                        </button>
                        <div class="btn-text-display center hide">Every 15 Minutes</div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="btn-freq-group">
                                <label for="select-list">Frequency</label>
                                <select class="form-control freq-btn" onfocus='this.size=4;' onblur='this.size=1;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();'id="select-list">
                                    <option selected="selected" value="every 15 minutes">Every 15 Minutes</option>
                                    <option value="hourly">Hourly</option>
                                    <option value="twice daily">Twice Daily</option>
                                    <option value="weekly">Weekly</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="twice-daily-btn hide">
                                <label for="time-one">Select First Time:</label>
                                <select onfocus='this.size=4;' onblur='this.size=1;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();' class="form-control" id="time-one">
                                    <option selected="selected">12 AM</option>
                                    <option>1 AM</option>
                                    <option>2 AM</option>
                                    <option>3 AM</option>
                                    <option>4 AM</option>
                                    <option>5 AM</option>
                                    <option>6 AM</option>
                                    <option>7 AM</option>
                                    <option>8 AM</option>
                                    <option>9 AM</option>
                                    <option>10 AM</option>
                                    <option>11 AM</option>
                                    <option>12 PM</option>
                                    <option>1 PM</option>
                                    <option>2 PM</option>
                                    <option>3 PM</option>
                                    <option>4 PM</option>
                                    <option>5 PM</option>
                                    <option>6 PM</option>
                                    <option>7 PM</option>
                                    <option>8 PM</option>
                                    <option>9 PM</option>
                                    <option>10 PM</option>
                                    <option>11 PM</option>
                                </select>
                                <label for="time-two">Select Second Time:</label>
                                <select onfocus='this.size=4;' onblur='this.size=1;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();' class="form-control" id="time-two">
                                    <option>12 AM</option>
                                    <option>1 AM</option>
                                    <option>2 AM</option>
                                    <option>3 AM</option>
                                    <option>4 AM</option>
                                    <option>5 AM</option>
                                    <option>6 AM</option>
                                    <option>7 AM</option>
                                    <option>8 AM</option>
                                    <option>9 AM</option>
                                    <option>10 AM</option>
                                    <option>11 AM</option>
                                    <option selected="selected">12 PM</option>
                                    <option>1 PM</option>
                                    <option>2 PM</option>
                                    <option>3 PM</option>
                                    <option>4 PM</option>
                                    <option>5 PM</option>
                                    <option>6 PM</option>
                                    <option>7 PM</option>
                                    <option>8 PM</option>
                                    <option>9 PM</option>
                                    <option>10 PM</option>
                                    <option>11 PM</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="weekly hide">
                                <label for="day">Select A Day:</label>
                                <select onfocus='this.size=4;' onblur='this.size=1;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();' class="form-control" id="day">
                                    <option selected="selected">Monday</option>
                                    <option>Tuesday</option>
                                    <option>Wednesday</option>
                                    <option>Thursday</option>
                                    <option>Friday</option>
                                    <option>Saturday</option>
                                    <option>Sunday</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" class="notify-check">
                <span class="slider round"></span>
            </label>
            <div class="disabled-overlay"></div>
            <div id="accordion2">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
                        <button class="btn btn-title center" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">PRICE <i class="caret-icon fas fa-caret-down hide"></i>
                        </button>
                        <div class="btn-text-display center hide">Every 15 Minutes</div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion2">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="btn-freq-group">
                                <label for="select-list">Frequency</label>
                                <select class="form-control freq-btn" onfocus='this.size=4;' onblur='this.size=1;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();'id="select-list">
                                    <option selected="selected" value="every 15 minutes">Every 15 Minutes</option>
                                    <option value="hourly">Hourly</option>
                                    <option value="twice daily">Twice Daily</option>
                                    <option value="weekly">Weekly</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="twice-daily-btn hide">
                                <label for="time-one">Select First Time:</label>
                                <select onfocus='this.size=4;' onblur='this.size=1;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();' class="form-control" id="time-one">
                                    <option selected="selected">12 AM</option>
                                    <option>1 AM</option>
                                    <option>2 AM</option>
                                    <option>3 AM</option>
                                    <option>4 AM</option>
                                    <option>5 AM</option>
                                    <option>6 AM</option>
                                    <option>7 AM</option>
                                    <option>8 AM</option>
                                    <option>9 AM</option>
                                    <option>10 AM</option>
                                    <option>11 AM</option>
                                    <option>12 PM</option>
                                    <option>1 PM</option>
                                    <option>2 PM</option>
                                    <option>3 PM</option>
                                    <option>4 PM</option>
                                    <option>5 PM</option>
                                    <option>6 PM</option>
                                    <option>7 PM</option>
                                    <option>8 PM</option>
                                    <option>9 PM</option>
                                    <option>10 PM</option>
                                    <option>11 PM</option>
                                </select>
                                <label for="time-two">Select Second Time:</label>
                                <select onfocus='this.size=4;' onblur='this.size=1;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();' class="form-control" id="time-two">
                                    <option>12 AM</option>
                                    <option>1 AM</option>
                                    <option>2 AM</option>
                                    <option>3 AM</option>
                                    <option>4 AM</option>
                                    <option>5 AM</option>
                                    <option>6 AM</option>
                                    <option>7 AM</option>
                                    <option>8 AM</option>
                                    <option>9 AM</option>
                                    <option>10 AM</option>
                                    <option>11 AM</option>
                                    <option selected="selected">12 PM</option>
                                    <option>1 PM</option>
                                    <option>2 PM</option>
                                    <option>3 PM</option>
                                    <option>4 PM</option>
                                    <option>5 PM</option>
                                    <option>6 PM</option>
                                    <option>7 PM</option>
                                    <option>8 PM</option>
                                    <option>9 PM</option>
                                    <option>10 PM</option>
                                    <option>11 PM</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="weekly hide">
                                <label for="day">Select A Day:</label>
                                <select onfocus='this.size=4;' onblur='this.size=1;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();' class="form-control" id="day">
                                    <option selected="selected">Monday</option>
                                    <option>Tuesday</option>
                                    <option>Wednesday</option>
                                    <option>Thursday</option>
                                    <option>Friday</option>
                                    <option>Saturday</option>
                                    <option>Sunday</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

$(document).ready(function() {


$(".btn-title").click(function() {
    $(".caret-icon").toggleClass('fa-caret-up fa-caret-down');
});

$(".freq-btn").change(function() {
    var str = "";
    $(".freq-btn option:selected").each(function() {
        str += $(this).text();
    });
    $(".btn-text-display").empty();
    $(".btn-text-display").text(str);
    if ($(this).val() == 'twice daily') {
        $('.twice-daily-btn').show();
    }
    else $('.twice-daily-btn').hide();
    if ($(this).val() == 'weekly') {
        $('.weekly').show();
    }
    else $('.weekly').hide();
}).change();
$('.notify-check').change(function(){
    $(".caret-icon").toggleClass("hide");
    $(".disabled-overlay").toggleClass("hide");
    $(".btn-text-display").toggleClass("hide");
    if($(".collapse").hasClass("show"))  {
        $(".collapse").toggleClass("show");
        $(".caret-icon").toggleClass('fa-caret-up fa-caret-down');
    }
});
$(".disabled-overlay").css({"width": ($("#accordion").width() + "px")});    

});

$( window ).resize(function() {
  $(".disabled-overlay").css({"width": ($("#accordion").width() + "px")});  
});
```

Comment: You're accessing the elements by class and the two instances share a class name. So it's doing what you told it to do. Either give the second instance different class names or access by some other selector.

Comment: @peeebeee but is there not a way to use the JQuery to loop through per accordion with the class names? Like object oriented scripts?

Comment: There are many ways of doing what you want. @peeebeee is right, it does what you told it to do. I would suggest to make use of functons if you don't want to write the code again.

Comment: @toffler Should I put all my JQuery in a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is when you select an element inside an event handler. Instead to find directly the element like (referring in this way to all):

```
$(".caret-icon")
```

you need to traverse up the dom till the first common ancestor and use it to find the right element like:

```
$(this).closest('.col-12').find(".caret-icon")
```

In this case you may use the reduced format:

```
$(this).find(".caret-icon")
```

Take a look to the [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) for more details.

```js
$(".btn-title").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".caret-icon").toggleClass('fa-caret-up fa-caret-down');
});
$(".freq-btn").change(function() {
    var str = "";
    $(this).closest('.col-12').find(".freq-btn option:selected").each(function() {
        str += $(this).text();
    });
    $(this).closest('.col-12').find(".btn-text-display").empty();
    $(this).closest('.col-12').find(".btn-text-display").text(str);
    if ($(this).val() == 'twice daily') {
        $(this).closest('.col-12').find('.twice-daily-btn').show();
    }
    else $(this).closest('.col-12').find('.twice-daily-btn').hide();
    if ($(this).val() == 'weekly') {
        $(this).closest('.col-12').find('.weekly').show();
    }
    else $(this).closest('.col-12').find('.weekly').hide();
}).change();
$('.notify-check').change(function(){
    $(this).find(".caret-icon").toggleClass("hide");
    $(this).closest('.col-12').find(".disabled-overlay").toggleClass("hide");
    $(this).closest('.col-12').find(".btn-text-display").toggleClass("hide");
    if($(this).closest('.col-12').find(".collapse").hasClass("show"))  {
        $(this).closest('.col-12').find(".collapse").toggleClass("show");
        $(this).closest('.col-12').find(".caret-icon").toggleClass('fa-caret-up fa-caret-down');
    }
});
$(".disabled-overlay").css({"width": ($("#accordion").width() + "px")});
$( window ).resize(function() {
$(".disabled-overlay").css({"width": ($("#accordion").width() + "px")});
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: "roboto", "open-sans";
    padding-top: 5%;
}
body .disabled-overlay {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
body .hide {
    display: none;
}
body .center {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1% 0;
}
body .switch {
    position: absolute;
    width: 45px;
    height: 26px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 25px;
    z-index: 3;
}
body .switch input {
    display: none;
}
body .switch input:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #32CD32;
}
body .switch input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(18px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(18px);
    transform: translateX(18px);
}
body .switch input:focus + .slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}
body .switch .slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
body .switch .slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
body .switch .round {
    border-radius: 34px;
}
body .switch .round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
body .card {
    font-family: "roboto", "open-sans";
    background-color: #daefdb;
    z-index: 1;
}
body .card .card-header .btn.btn-title {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: none;
}
body .card .card-header .btn.btn-title:hover {
    color: #182ed6;
}
body .card .card-header .btn.btn-title:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
}
body .card .card-header .btn-text-display {
    font-size: 18px;
}
body .card .card-body label {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
}
body .card .card-body select, body .card .card-body option {
    font-size: 18px;
}
body .card .card-body .btn-freq-group {
    display: block;
}
body .card .card-body .btn-freq-group button {
    background-color: #b8e4ba;
    border: 1px solid #3e8e41;
    color: #3e8e41;
    padding: 10px 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
body .card .card-body .btn-freq-group button:hover, body .card .card-body .btn-freq-group button:active, body .card .card-body .btn-freq-group button:focus, body .card .card-body .btn-freq-group button.selected {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
    color: #b8e4ba;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" class="notify-check">
                <span class="slider round"></span>
            </label>
            <div class="disabled-overlay"></div>
            <div id="accordion">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                        <button class="btn btn-title center" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">PRICE <i class="caret-icon fas fa-caret-down hide"></i>
                        </button>
                        <div class="btn-text-display center hide">Every 15 Minutes</div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="btn-freq-group">
                                <label for="select-list">Frequency</label>
                                <select class="form-control freq-btn" onfocus='this.size=4;' onblur='this.size=1;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();'id="select-list">
                                    <option selected="selected" value="every 15 minutes">Every 15 Minutes</option>
                                    <option value="hourly">Hourly</option>
                                    <option value="twice daily">Twice Daily</option>
                                    <option value="weekly">Weekly</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="twice-daily-btn hide">
                                <label for="time-one">Select First Time:</label>
                                <select onfocus='this.size=4;' onblur='this.size=1;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();' class="form-control" id="time-one">
                                    <option selected="selected">12 AM</option>
                                    <option>1 AM</option>
                                    <option>2 AM</option>
                                    <option>3 AM</option>
                                    <option>4 AM</option>
                                    <option>5 AM</option>
                                    <option>6 AM</option>
                                    <option>7 AM</option>
                                    <option>8 AM</option>
                                    <option>9 AM</option>
                                    <option>10 AM</option>
                                    <option>11 AM</option>
                                    <option>12 PM</option>
                                    <option>1 PM</option>
                                    <option>2 PM</option>
                                    <option>3 PM</option>
                                    <option>4 PM</option>
                                    <option>5 PM</option>
                                    <option>6 PM</option>
                                    <option>7 PM</option>
                                    <option>8 PM</option>
                                    <option>9 PM</option>
                                    <option>10 PM</option>
                                    <option>11 PM</option>
                                </select>
                                <label for="time-two">Select Second Time:</label>
                                <select onfocus='this.size=4;' onblur='this.size=1;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();' class="form-control" id="time-two">
                                    <option>12 AM</option>
                                    <option>1 AM</option>
                                    <option>2 AM</option>
                                    <option>3 AM</option>
                                    <option>4 AM</option>
                                    <option>5 AM</option>
                                    <option>6 AM</option>
                                    <option>7 AM</option>
                                    <option>8 AM</option>
                                    <option>9 AM</option>
                                    <option>10 AM</option>
                                    <option>11 AM</option>
                                    <option selected="selected">12 PM</option>
                                    <option>1 PM</option>
                                    <option>2 PM</option>
                                    <option>3 PM</option>
                                    <option>4 PM</option>
                                    <option>5 PM</option>
                                    <option>6 PM</option>
                                    <option>7 PM</option>
                                    <option>8 PM</option>
                                    <option>9 PM</option>
                                    <option>10 PM</option>
                                    <option>11 PM</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="weekly hide">
                                <label for="day">Select A Day:</label>
                                <select onfocus='this.size=4;' onblur='this.size=1;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();' class="form-control" id="day">
                                    <option selected="selected">Monday</option>
                                    <option>Tuesday</option>
                                    <option>Wednesday</option>
                                    <option>Thursday</option>
                                    <option>Friday</option>
                                    <option>Saturday</option>
                                    <option>Sunday</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" class="notify-check">
                <span class="slider round"></span>
            </label>
            <div class="disabled-overlay"></div>
            <div id="accordion2">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
                        <button class="btn btn-title center" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">PRICE <i class="caret-icon fas fa-caret-down hide"></i>
                        </button>
                        <div class="btn-text-display center hide">Every 15 Minutes</div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion2">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="btn-freq-group">
                                <label for="select-list">Frequency</label>
                                <select class="form-control freq-btn" onfocus='this.size=4;' onblur='this.size=1;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();'id="select-list">
                                    <option selected="selected" value="every 15 minutes">Every 15 Minutes</option>
                                    <option value="hourly">Hourly</option>
                                    <option value="twice daily">Twice Daily</option>
                                    <option value="weekly">Weekly</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="twice-daily-btn hide">
                                <label for="time-one">Select First Time:</label>
                                <select onfocus='this.size=4;' onblur='this.size=1;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();' class="form-control" id="time-one">
                                    <option selected="selected">12 AM</option>
                                    <option>1 AM</option>
                                    <option>2 AM</option>
                                    <option>3 AM</option>
                                    <option>4 AM</option>
                                    <option>5 AM</option>
                                    <option>6 AM</option>
                                    <option>7 AM</option>
                                    <option>8 AM</option>
                                    <option>9 AM</option>
                                    <option>10 AM</option>
                                    <option>11 AM</option>
                                    <option>12 PM</option>
                                    <option>1 PM</option>
                                    <option>2 PM</option>
                                    <option>3 PM</option>
                                    <option>4 PM</option>
                                    <option>5 PM</option>
                                    <option>6 PM</option>
                                    <option>7 PM</option>
                                    <option>8 PM</option>
                                    <option>9 PM</option>
                                    <option>10 PM</option>
                                    <option>11 PM</option>
                                </select>
                                <label for="time-two">Select Second Time:</label>
                                <select onfocus='this.size=4;' onblur='this.size=1;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();' class="form-control" id="time-two">
                                    <option>12 AM</option>
                                    <option>1 AM</option>
                                    <option>2 AM</option>
                                    <option>3 AM</option>
                                    <option>4 AM</option>
                                    <option>5 AM</option>
                                    <option>6 AM</option>
                                    <option>7 AM</option>
                                    <option>8 AM</option>
                                    <option>9 AM</option>
                                    <option>10 AM</option>
                                    <option>11 AM</option>
                                    <option selected="selected">12 PM</option>
                                    <option>1 PM</option>
                                    <option>2 PM</option>
                                    <option>3 PM</option>
                                    <option>4 PM</option>
                                    <option>5 PM</option>
                                    <option>6 PM</option>
                                    <option>7 PM</option>
                                    <option>8 PM</option>
                                    <option>9 PM</option>
                                    <option>10 PM</option>
                                    <option>11 PM</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="weekly hide">
                                <label for="day">Select A Day:</label>
                                <select onfocus='this.size=4;' onblur='this.size=1;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();' class="form-control" id="day">
                                    <option selected="selected">Monday</option>
                                    <option>Tuesday</option>
                                    <option>Wednesday</option>
                                    <option>Thursday</option>
                                    <option>Friday</option>
                                    <option>Saturday</option>
                                    <option>Sunday</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```